# How efficiently I update and create new dataframes based on previous dataframes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Here I am cleaning my data based on previous data, but when I running through this. It runs fine but when measure time on 1000 rows it takes more time.

It is just a sample of what I am doing, I have mask or calculate data on more complex algorithms and methods.

Can suggest any enhancement or processing measures to do processing very efficiently in less time?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def method_1(data):
    return (data['A'] + 1) + (data['B'] * data['D'])


def method_2(data):
    if data['E'] == 'test' and data['D'] == 4:
        return 'test_1'
    elif data['E'] == 'train':
        return 'test_2'
    else:
        return None


def new_data():
    df = pd.DataFrame({'A': 1.,
                       'B': np.array([3] * 4),
                       'C': pd.Series(1, index=list(range(4)), dtype='float32'),
                       'D': np.array([3, 1, 4, 4], dtype='int32'),
                       'E': pd.Categorical(["test", "train", "test", "train"]),
                       'F': 'foo'})

    # Output
    #        A B    C  D      E    F
    #   0  1.0 3  1.0  3   test  foo
    #   1  1.0 3  1.0  3  train  foo
    #   2  1.0 3  1.0  3   test  foo
    #   3  1.0 3  1.0  3  train  foo

    n_df = []
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        d = pd.Series()
        d['A_1'] = method_1(row)
        d['E_1'] = method_2(row)
        d['A'] = row['A']
        d['B'] = row['B']
        d['C'] = row['C']

        n_df.append(d)

    n_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(n_df)

    print(n_df)

    # Output

    #       A_1     E_1    A  B    C
    #   0  10.0    None  1.0  3  1.0
    #   1   4.0  test_2  1.0  3  1.0
    #   2  13.0  test_1  1.0  3  1.0
    #   3  13.0  test_2  1.0  3  1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't add a comment yet, I'll be writing here and making edits so I can try to help you.

It looks there is a *typo* here (even if it still runs):

```
def method_1(data):
    return data['A'] + 1 * + data['B'] * data['D']
                          ^
```

Also, these lines:

```
'B': np.array([3] * 4),
'D': np.array([3, 1, 4, 4], dtype='int32'),
```

should reproduce a different output as the one you provided:

```
#                B  D                              B  D
#   0   2013-01-02  3                          0   3  3
#   1   2013-01-02  3   ----> should be ---->  1   3  1
#   2   2013-01-02  3                          2   3  4
#   3   2013-01-02  3                          3   3  4
```

Can you review that so I can better understand what are your methods doing?

---

I've worked on it ignoring the small issues I pointed at above. The following code might make it all set for you:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': 1.,
                   'B': np.full(4,3),
                   'C': pd.Series(1, index=list(range(4)), dtype='float32'),
                   'D': np.array([3, 1, 4, 4], dtype='int32'),
                   'E': pd.Categorical(["test", "train", "test", "train"]),
                   'F': 'foo'})


n_df = df.copy()

n_df['A_1'] = df['A'] + df['B'] * df['D']

n_df['E_1'] = ['test_1' if (df['E'][i] == 'test' and df['D'][i] == 4) 

                        else 'test_2' if (df['E'][i] == 'train') else None for i in df.index]
```

Comment: You could also bypass making a copy by adding the columns 'A_1' and 'E_1' to the original DataFrame instead, since the other columns won't change

Comment: An observation: Method_2 is reasonably simple so it could be dealt with by making use of a list comprehension. If you want to manipulate the data in more complex means, a list comprehension might not be too appropriate.

Comment: I am just trying to make you understand using dummy example. Actually I have number of complex algorithms and calculation on each column value based on multiple columns values. I just want different approaches to get result out of that efficiently.

Comment: Sure :) I tried running on a big DataFrame (100K rows) and it did pretty fast. Surely  though not as the fastest as it could be...